# Incoporar paginación

Tags: laravel, paginación

Quisiera saber si alguien podría orientarme acerca de cómo se incorpora la paginación en laravel 5.6, si tengo un SQL armado de manera explícita, es decir, la consulta en mi modelo está de la siguiente manera:

```
public function getVentaAcumuladaAnualXTienda($filtro, $from, $campos, $groupby, $date, $cc){

     $rows = "";
     if($groupby != "")
     $rows = ", id_empleado "; 

     $sql = "SELECT distinct(al.id_almacen), al.des_almacen, sum(venta_ytd) as ventaactual, sum(venta_ppto) as ventapptoactual, sum(venta_yld$cc) as ventaanterior, sum(venta_proy) as proyactual   
    FROM dim.almacen as al, fact.venta_comparada_extendida as T1 
     $from   
    WHERE T1.id_calendario BETWEEN $date[0] and $date[1]     
            AND T1.id_almacen = al.id_almacen 
             $filtro   
    GROUP BY al.id_almacen, al.des_almacen 
    ORDER BY al.id_almacen";

  $listado  = DB::connection('comments')->select($sql);
  return $listado;
}
```

Y al sustituir

```
   $listado  = DB::connection('comments')->select($sql);

      POR

   $listado  = DB::connection('comments')->select($sql)->paginate(15);
```

Me arroja el error:

```
      Call to a member function paginate() on array
```

Por lo que quisiera saber, ¿cómo hacer la paginación en ése caso?.
Valga acotar que el SQL está hecho de ésta manera porque es un query dinámico, se pueden incorporar otros filtros y tablas según lo requerido por el usuario.

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que debes cambiar tu consulta para usar métodos de Laravel para poder paginar. Este es un punto de partida para tu consulta, tendrás que ajustarlo con lo que falta pero creo que te puede valer:

```
DB::connection('comments')
    ->table('dim.almacen AS al')
    ->join('fact.venta_comparada_extendida AS T1', 'T1.id_almacen', '=', 'al.id_almacen')
    ->select(al.des_almacen')   
    ->whereBetween('T1.id_calendario, [$date[0], $date[1]])
    ->groupBy('al.id_almacen', 'al.des_almacen')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Esta solución ya la había intentado, pero no encuentro cómo incorporar los campos sum ni el distinct con el query builder de laravel

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacerlo con algo así: `->select(DB::raw('sum(venta_proy) as proyactual'))`?

Answer (score 0):

Después de varios intentos por modificar el query a las "convenciones" laravel, he conseguido hacer la paginación utilizando el query como lo he trabajado, dejo la respuesta por si a alguien llegara a necesitar algo parecido.
Anivel de controller

```
  $listado = $model->getVentaAcumuladaMensual($filtro, $from, $campos, $groupby, $date, $cc);
    //paginación
    $filter_products = []; // Manual filter or your array for pagination
    if(!isset($request['page']))
        $request['page'] = 1;
    $page = $request['page']; // current page for pagination
    $perPage = 15;              //número de registros por página
    foreach($listado as $item){
        $n = $request['page'] * $perPage;
        if($i< $n){
            array_push($filter_products, $item);  //arreglo de registros que se mostrarán en cada página
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $count = count($listado); // total product for pagination
    // manually slice array of product to display on page
    $offset = ($page-1) * $perPage;
    $products = array_slice($filter_products, $offset, $perPage);
    // your pagination 
    $listado1 = new Paginator($products, $count, $perPage, $page, ['path'  => $request->url(),'query' => $request->query(), ]);

    //dd($listado);
    return view('reportes.venta_mes')->with('listado', $listado1->appends( Input::except('page')))
```